# Python wrapper for UDT C++ library

Tags: python, wrapper, boost-python, udp-data-transfer

I want to use the [UDT library](http://udt.sourceforge.net/) in Python, so I need a wrapper. I found this one: [pyudt](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyudt/0.1a), but I dont know exactly how to use this to send files from a peer to peer. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

after so many time I've found this question and its solution:

The steps to install pyudt-0.1a are:

- install:
  libboost-python1.46-dev or equivalent
  (for instance, in linux-ubuntu12.04 it's in the reps.)
- install udt.h (from: http://sourceforge.net/projects/udt/) into a system directory,

OR

(put the udt.h file in the same path as the pyudt-0.1a files, and then change a line of the "pyudt.cpp", from:

```
#include <udt.h>
```

to:

```
#include "udt.h"
```

).

- update the version of boost_python library, in "setup.py" to the one you're
  using,

eg.:

```
    ... libraries=['udt', 'boost_python-py27'])
```

- change the following line(s) in "pyudt.cpp":

you ***must*** correct a bug, changing from:

```
int r = UDT::send(_sock, data.c_str(), data.length(), 0);
```

to:

```
int r = UDT::send(_sock, data.c_str(), data.length()+1, 0);
```

because the character "\0" meaning the end of string must also be sent, otherwise junk would be appended to your string.

optionally, you may choose between:

```
   _sock = UDT::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);   --» default
```

or:

```
   _sock = UDT::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);  --» optional
```

- finally, run,

in the corresponding folder:

```
python2.7 ./setup.py build
sudo python2.7 ./setup.py install
```

OR, (if you don't have admin permissions to install it for all the users, and just wanna try it for you:

```
python2.7 ./setup.py build
python2.7 ./setup.py install --prefix=~/pyudt-0.1a/installation_dir/  #in this case, pyudt would only work if called from that directory
```

)

Then, the code for a simple client can be:

```
import pyudt
socket = pyudt.pyudt_socket()
socket.connect(("127.0.0.1", 7000))
socket.send("hello_world!")
```

and it works, it talks with my cpp server!

notice: if you need more help you can write in the python's console:

```
import pyudt
dir(pyudt.pyudt_socket) # to list the available functions
help(pyudt)             # to get more help
```

PS. the files created with this installation tutorial are:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyudt.so, and /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyudt-0.1a.egg-info

Answer (score 1):

You can give my [udt_py fork](https://github.com/lilydjwg/udt_py) a try. It includes a sample `recvfile.py` now and can retrieve files from the `sendfile` daemon in udt's `app` directory.